# How to find the the probability using mean and standard deviation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The IQs of $9$ randomly selected people are recorded. Let $\overline{Y}$ denote their average. Assuming the distribution from which the $Y_i$'s were drawn is normal with a mean of $100$ and a standard deviation of $16$, what is the probability that $\overline{Y}$ will exceed $103$?

What is the probability that any arbitrary $Y_i$ will exceed $103$?

What is the probability that exactly three of the $Y_i$'s will exceed $103$?

Comment: Use `\overline{Y}` to get $\overline{Y}$.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I believe I found  the probability that any arbitrary $Y_i$ will exceed 103 is $0.4286$.
I am having trouble finding what $\overline{Y}$. 
I am also very uncertain how to find the probability of exactly $3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Y_1, Y_2, \dots,Y_9$ be the IQ measurements. Then 
$$\bar{Y}=\frac{Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_9}{9}.$$
It is a standard fact that I imagine you know that under your assumptions, $\bar{Y}$ has normal distribution, with mean the mean of the $Y_i$, and standard deviation $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{9}}$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the $Y_i$.

Thus in our case, the standard deviation of $\bar{Y}$ is $\frac{16}{3}$.

Now we tackle the problem of the probability that $\bar{Y}\gt 103$. Here there is some ambiguity, because published IQ's are usually integers. But we will assume they can be in principle any real number. Then
$$\Pr(\bar{Y}\gt 103)=\Pr\left(Z\gt \frac{103-100}{16/3}\right),$$
where $Z$ is standard normal. You can now obtain the probability from a table of the standard normal, or software.  I think the answer is about $0.2868$.

For the second problem and third problem, let $p$ be the probability that an individual's IQ exceeds $103$. This is the probability that a standard normal is $\gt \frac{103-100}{16}$, and can be found using a table or software.

I get about $0.4257$. This is close to your answer, so I am sure you did it more or less the right way. I am almost sure that you rounded $\frac{3}{16}$ to $0.18$. It is actually $0.1875$, so three-quarters of the way to $0.19$.

Call exceeding $103$ a **success**. We want the probability of exactly $3$ successes in $9$ trials. For the answer, we use the Binomial distribution. The required probability is
$$\binom{9}{3}p^3(1-p)^6.$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes much more sense now!

Comment: Good! It takes a little while to see how these things work, but after you have it figured out, it stays with you.